# create button become hidden after submit button click How to prevent this behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I work on asp.net core 7 razor page . I face issue after select item option and click submit button

create button become hidden so How to prevent this behavior .

**my issue when selected item option have value and click submit button then create button
become hidden and correct must be still shown because select option have value .**

code below working only before click submit button but after click submit button not work

what I try on my code

if select option value 0 then hide create button else show create button .

```
   function toggleButtonVisibility() {
        var selectedIndex = $('#branch-select').prop('selectedIndex');
        if (selectedIndex == 0) {
            $('#createTxt').hide();
        } else {
            $('#createTxt').show();
               
        }
    }
```

form submit code as below :

```
<form id="FrmShelfLabelPrintrSetup" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm() ">

         
                  
                        <select id="branch-select" asp-for="SelectedBranchId" name="selectbranchid" class="form-select" style="margin-left:3px;font-size:15px;font-family: 'Open Sans' , sans-serif;font-weight: bold;" onchange="toggleButtonVisibility()">
                            <option value="0">--Select--</option>
                            @foreach (var branches in Model.branches)
                            {

                                <option value="@branches.iBranchCode">@branches.vBranchDesc</option>


                            }
                        </select>
                       
                   
                      
                        <button  id="Searchtxt" type="submit" name="searchButton" value="search" asp-page-handler="Search" style="width:100px;margin-top:7px;" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                        <button id="createTxt" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CreateshelflabelModal" style="width:100px;margin-top:7px;margin-left:7px;display:none;" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>

                 

        </form>
```

on razor csharp page model as below :

```
public async Task OnPostSearchAsync(string selectbranchid)
    {
       string errormsg = "";

       
        if(dtresults.Rows.Count>0)
        {
            ViewData["SearchResults"] = dtresults;
        }
        else
        {
            errormsg = "No Records Available";
        }
        
        
       

       
    }
```

**updated post**

**before click submit button exactly happen below**

if select option 0 create button become hidden

if select option have value and bigger than 0 then create button will show

**after click submit button this my issue**

if select option have value and bigger than 0 then create button will be hidden why it must be show because select option have value

I check page it not loaded page again as posted code not return page

Comment: `create button become hidden so How to prevent this behavior` don't call `hide()` on it. If you need more specific help, then please edit your question to provide more descriptive details of your issue and goal as right now it's very unclear.

Comment: So your form is submitted. Is the page is loading back up with the original selected values in the form submission? Seems like you want to call `toggleButtonVisibility()` on page load.

Comment: my issue after submit click create button hidden and based on my java script function it hide when no item selected and if selected item option have value then create button hidden so why it hidden after sumit

Comment: can you show me How call toggleButtonVisibility() on page load.

Comment: @ahmedabdelaziz `$(document).ready(function () { toggleButtonVisibility() });`

Comment: can you please add this as answer to my question to increase vote to my account